# Action permission error with Stream API

Tags: ruby, jwt, httparty, getstream-io

I keep getting "You do not have permission to perform this action." when attempting to connect. What am I missing?

```
url = 'https://api.getstream.io/api/v1.0/feed/user/12353253/?api_key=API_KEY'

payload = {
  'resource' => 'feed',
  'action' => 'read',
  'feed_id' => 'user:12353253'
}

token = JWT.encode(payload, secret, 'HS256')

options[:headers] = {
  'Authorization' => token,
  'stream-auth-type' => 'jwt'
}

response = HTTParty.get(url, options)
```

Comment: Are you passing in an actual API key?

Comment: Yes, API_KEY is just for this example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you got everything right except for the value for `feed_id` in the payload. It should be the "user12353253" instead of "user:12353253" (no semicolon).

P.S.
I am one of the founders of Stream, REST API does not explain this well. We will update them asap.

Comment: That was it. I figured that out after digging through the ruby client. The naming standards in the docs need updated, just FYI. https://getstream.io/docs_rest/#naming Thanks for your help and very cool product.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a requirement to use HTTParty? [Stream has a Ruby library](https://github.com/GetStream/stream-ruby) that makes this much, much easier and does the JWT work behind the scenes for you.

```
client = Stream::Client.new('API_KEY', 'API_SECRET', :location => 'us-east')
user_feed = client.feed('user', 12353253.to_s)
results = user_feed.get(:limit => 10)
```

By default, this should do JWT for you.

If you really want to do it yourself, you can trace what the client library is doing and reproduce that.

Comment: Can't use the libraries unfortunately and the REST API docs are missing important information that differs from the standard.

Comment: @Stephen what is the blocking issue that prevents you from using the API client? Perhaps this is something that can be fixed on the library.